# Conflicts are not shown during Git rebase

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rebase

I am facing a weird issue while trying to rebase a branch with master branch. Scenario is as given below:

- I had to create a new branch using the a commit which is 21 commits behind master.
- Checked out to the particular commit `git checkout git checkout <sha>`
- Created new local branch `git switch -c feature_branch`
- Pushed the local branch to remote `git push origin feature_branch`
- I do have some changes in the newly created branch `feature_branch` compared to `master`.
- Now I want to rebase my `feature_branch` with the master
  `git rebase master`.

  ````
  First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
  Fast-forwarded feature_branch to master.```
  ````
- The changes in the `feature_branch` has been over-written by `master` and no conflicts were shown during the rebase.

Could anybody please explain what is going on here. It would be really helpful, as I maybe missing some basics here.

Thank you

Comment: Your description and your command output does not match. If you your branches have diverged (i.e. each has commits of their own, not contained in the other), you cannot get "fast-forwarding". Are you sure your `feature_branch` has commits not in master? Also, "fast-forwarding" is something you get when _merging_, NOT when rebasing. I'm unable to reproduce. Either I get "Current branch is up to date" or "Successfully rebased and updated" when calling `git rebase`

Comment: I had to create ```feature_branch``` using one of the commits for example ```bug_fix_commit``` from ```master```. 
And in master changes related to ```bug_fix_commit``` has been reverted manually. 
So there are file changes in ```feature_branch``` compared to ```master```. 
Please let me know if the issue description is not clear.

Comment: So feature is fully contained in master? `master` contains commits not in `feature`, but `feature` contains only commits from `master` and no commits of its own? That's a fast-forward _merge_ and rebasing will have no commits to rebase (because all commits are already in the target). What is your expectation when you run the command? "rebase" copies commits from the source to the target (there are no source commits in your question) and "merge" applies differences from both sides. There is only one side in your question, so no conflicts are expected.

Comment: I was expecting that the changes done in commit ```bug_fix_commit``` in ```feature_branch``` will be shown as merge conflict as the changes are not matching with ```master```.

Comment: I am trying to get the changes done in ```bug_fix_commit``` + changes in ```master```. 
Basically, while applying the master changes I want to retain the ```bug_fix_commit``` changes.

Comment: Conflicts only appear when different commits touch the same line of code (and change it differently). And I'm confused. Is `bug_fix_commit` a commit on master (your first comment) or a commit from feature_branch (your latest comment)? Does the commit change the same lines as other commits? If yes => conflicts very likely, if no => patch can apply cleanly, no conflicts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234049/discussion-between-kk2491-and-knittl).

Comment: ```bug_fix_commit``` was a commit in master. Later the changes done in ```bug_fix_commit``` has been reverted back manually in master. 
Now if I create a branch ```feature_brach``` out of ```bug_fix_commit``` it will have the changes which should be conflicting with the latest master as the changes in master are reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase <target> [<source>]` will take all commits from `source` (defaults to your current branch) and *copy* them one-by-one to the target. If source is fully contained in target (i.e. all commits of source are also in target), then there are no commits to copy. Rebase is effectively a no-op, with the exception of moving the branch label of source to the same commit as target.

Think of it as *commits*, as shown by `git log --oneline --graph source...target` (3 dots), not as changes as shown by `git diff source target`. You can preview the commits that would be rebased by running `git log --oneline target..source`—if the output is empty, there are no commits to rebase (source is fully contained in target).

---

If you want to duplicate the commit on master, you have (at least) three options, depending on the exact content of the commits:

1. [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

   ```
   git checkout master
   git cherry-pick bug_fix_commit
   ```
2. [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)ing the revert:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git revert revert_of_bug_fix_commit
   ```
3. Instruct rebase to not compute the range of commits automatically, but manually supply the range to copy:

   ```
   git rebase --onto master feature_branch^ feature_branch
   ```